# Next.js - html-react-parser + <Image> solved Image aspect ratio

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If I am not wrong there is mandatory to use width + height for `<Image />` component to have correct aspect ratio in next.js.
E.g. discussed in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18497

[1] this will not work:

```
<Image width="500" src="https://www.abc.de/fgh.jpg" />
```

Error: Image with src " https://www.abc.de/fgh.jpg " must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.

[2] but combination `html-react-parser` + `<Image />` works without error as expected:

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser'
parse( '<Image width="500" src="https://www.abc.de/fgh.jpg" />' )
```

Can be [2] valid solution?

Comment: Can you check in inspect if you're still making use of the image optimization that nextjs Image provides. It may not be throwing an error but also the optimization may not work and the image may be processed as a regular <img>

Comment: You are right, `html-react-parser` converts `<Image />` to regular `<img>`. It means no image optimization. There is jpg instead smaller WebP. Thank you!